# In app browser event is not working in iOS device

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on the hybrid app

For Paytm integration,  I used the in-app browser method

```
var browser = this.iab.create('http://url?ORDER_ID='+result.orderid+'&CUST_ID='+this.cust_id+'&TXN_AMOUNT='+result.total,'_blank','location=no,hardwareback=no,zoom=yes');


browser.on('loadstop').subscribe((event) => {   
if (event.url.match("returnprocess.php")) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        browser.close();
        let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Back to order, wait a minutes'
        })
        loader.present();
        loader.dismiss();
    }, 5000);

//then push to next page
```

The above code is working fine on Android device. But in IOS device it is not returned to APP.

I googled a lot. But I couldn't find the right solution. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?